# i'm not sure what function I want for this

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I have a column that holds the month number(1....60)  I want in another column to indicate what the number "1" is  (in this case January 2023)   I need a formula to look at a column, if the number is "1" return the date  Jan 2023 to another column, same row.
to help I have two columns listed with the reference between number and date...i.e month 1=Jan 2023, month 2=February 2023...and on for 5 years.
In summary
Row 23  column F equals "1"  I want the physical month and year in A 23
At the bottom of the sheet I have columns like this: date      number
jan 2023    1
Feb 2023    2
...and so on... I need help.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

[image: sequence]

Given that "jan 2023" is not a date (*1 jan 2023 is a date*) and assuming that cell `A2` contains that value as the **starting date**,  you can get the desired result by entering this formula in cell `B2`:

```
=index(date(year(A2),month(A2)+sequence(60)-1,1))
```

*note that `column B` must be formatted as a date and that there is no need for any other helper columns*